# Color scale conditional formatting for mix of text and number in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I would like to use the color scale conditional format on a column in Excel. I had to change some of the numbers to text because I wanted to distinguish between when the value was <1% and actually 0%. But when I did that, it messed up the color scale:
[image]

You can see that when there is text that reads "<1%" it removes the color formatting. How do I make it keep the formatting for those? I'd like it to be the same color as 0%.

Comment: Setup a second condition for when the cell's value is `="<1%"`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad that will not integrate in the color scale, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a conditional format with the following formula:

```
=AND(A1>0,A1<0.01)
```

And apply the following custom number format:

```
<1%
```

Then apply the second condition with the gradient.

[image]

You should end up with something like this:

[image]

(note the value of cell `A1`)

Comment: I did not realize you could create multiple conditional formats! Thank you!!

Comment: If that answer works for you, then you should [accept it](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers). That way everyone will know your question has been asnwered.